# networkx use strings in add_edges_frim

Tags: python, networkx

I successfully added edges using integers with networkx as in :

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(3,6)])
```

When I try doing the same with strings I get an error:

```
import networkx as nx
    G = nx.Graph()

    G.add_edges_from([('emailId$6', 'phoneId$6', 'otherId$4'),('emailId$6', 'phoneId$23', 'otherId$1')])



ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

How can I add strings as edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edges link two nodes, you are trying to add an edge between three nodes (that does not make sense in graph theory)

This works fine :

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edges_from([('emailId$6', 'phoneId$6'),('emailId$6', 'phoneId$23')]
```